# BFS in non binary tree in java

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, tree, breadth-first-search

I have to find the element level wise (Breath first search). I wrote the code but its not working correctly need help example **:**
**Node A** has child **B,C,D** and **Node B** has child **E,F,G,H** it should output ***A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H*** according to BFS rules but my code displaying ***A,B,E,F,G,H,D***

```
private void BF_Search(Node node,Node toFind,Queue<Node> qu)
{
    if(node.getData().getName().equals(toFind.getData().getName()))
         if(node.getData().getYOB()==toFind.getData().getYOB())
         {
             for(Node nde:qu)
             {
                 System.out.println(nde.getData().getName()+"  "+nde.getData().getYOB());
             }
             return;
         }

    for(Node nodes:node.getChildren())
    {
        qu.add(nodes);
        BF_Search(nodes,toFind,qu);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working correctly"?  What's going wrong?

Comment: tree is not binary tree as in video its for binary tree @jemeson

Comment: **Node A** has child  **B,C,D**  Node B has child  **E,F,G,H** it should output **A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H** according to BFS rules but my code displaying  **A,B,E,F,G,H,D**

Comment: I cannot see that the algorithm in the video is specifically for binary trees. It will work with all trees.

Comment: @striker this is not `bfs` rather it is `dfs`. Clearly you are recursively going into each child.